# HTML5 Canvas - lines drawn disappears in a flash

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have two canvases layered one over the other.

```
<div class="center">
  <canvas id="imgcanvas" style="position:absolute;margin:0 0 0 0;z-index:1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="drawcanvas" style="position:absolute;margin:0 0 0 0;z-index:2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Below the canvas, I have a horizontal thumbnail pallete.  Upon clicking the thumbnail, the clicked image renders in the image canvas.  I am using the `drawcanvas` to draw lines on the canvas.  The coordinates for drawing the lines are stored in the localStorage.

Upon clicking the thumbnail, along with loading the image, I am trying to draw the lines taking the coordinates from the localStorage.  However, the lines get drawn and disappears in a flash of a second.

The following is the code:

```
//clicked_id is returned by the thumbnail

function clickedImage(clicked_id) {
  localStorage.setItem('sel_id', clicked_id);
  //Get the complete path of the image
  var clickedImg = document.getElementById(clicked_id).src;
  var activeImg = document.getElementById(clicked_id).src;

  //store the complete path
  localStorage.setItem("activeImg",activeImg);
  var clickedImg = basename(clickedImg,"/");
  localStorage.setItem("clickedImage", clickedImg);
  var clickedImg = clickedImg.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

  //draw lines on canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById("imgcanvas");
  var regcanvas = document.getElementById("drawcanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var ctxr = regcanvas.getContext("2d");
  var arr = new Array();
    //Perform calculations to get the fourth coordinate
    arr = fourthCoord(getArray(arr));
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i][0] === clickedImg) {
        first.x = arr[i][3];
        first.y = arr[i][4]; 
        second.x = arr[i][5]; 
        second.y = arr[i][6]; 
        third.x = arr[i][7]; 
        third.y = arr[i][8]; 
        fourth.x = arr[i][9]; 
        fourth.y = arr[i][10]; 
        ctxr.lineCap = "round";
        ctxr.lineWidth = 3;
        ctxr.strokeStyle = '#f4d03f';
        ctxr.beginPath();
        ctxr.moveTo(first.x,first.y);
        ctxr.lineTo(second.x,second.y);
        ctxr.lineTo(third.x,third.y);
        ctxr.lineTo(fourth.x,fourth.y);
        ctxr.lineTo(first.x,first.y);
        ctxr.stroke();
        console.log(first,second,third,fourth);
      }
    }

  //Load the image
  var thumbNails = document.getElementById("loaded_img_panel");
  var pic = new Image();
  pic.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = pic.width;
    canvas.height = pic.height;
    regcanvas.width = pic.width;
    regcanvas.height = pic.height;
    ctx.drawImage(pic, 0,0)
  }

  thumbNails.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
    pic.src = event.target.src;  
  });
}
```

The getArray() function gets the coordinates for the lines.  I am using the same codes on a sample canvas, where clicking on the canvas (instead of clicking on the image) draws the lines. However on this application, the lines get drawn (which I could see for a fraction of a second) and then disappears.

Trial 1:

I called in two functions onclick of thumbNail - clickedImage() and drawAnnotations().  I moved all the codes pertaining to drawing lines into drawAnnotations().  This did not work.

Trial 2:

I called in the first function clickedImage() on mousedown event of the thumbnail and drawAnnotations() on the mouseup event of the thumbnail.  This too did not work.

Trial 3:

I created a window.addEventListener...and called drawAnnotation function onload

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById('drawcanvas').addEventListener("load", drawAnnotations);
});
```

this too did not work...meaning...it draws the lines...but disappears in a flash.

Comment: Can you publish example on jsfiddle.com?

Comment: Setting your canvas width ot height will clear it (and reset all its contexts properties). You are doing this in your image onload handler. So move your drawing operations after you did set the dimensions and you should be good

Comment: @Kaiido  Thank you...I tried a few things without much success...have edited my question with trials done....Could you please help me on how do I move the drawing operations post setting the dimensions?

Comment: @Kaiido  Thank you for your guidance....your tip helped. I had the two handlers that reset the canvas width and height - thumbnail onclick and window onload - when I disabled resize on window onload and retained thumbnail onclick and moved the code inside pic.onload, everything worked.  I can accept your comment as an answer.